# Playing .mp4 files in a .swf gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, flash, mp4, swfobject

I have a gallery on the site I'm working on that displays work for a portfolio.  On the right is a vertical set of stills that, when clicked on, produce the swf/image on the left and, below that, a description that correlates to each one.  The problem is that I've added in .mp4s and the code I've written for them isn't working.  It's not a problem with the HTML or CSS because everything else is working - even the description for the .mp4 pops up when the still for it is clicked on.  The only problem is that the main player box - which shows the .swfs .jpg images just fine - loads nothing when I click on the video.  I've put the JQuery code below.  I have only rudimentary understanding of JQuery, so I don't know if I'm just wrong or it can't be done - please help if you can!

> ```
>    <script> 
>        function putSWF(swf){ 
>           params = {wmode:"opaque"};
>           console.log(params);
>           swfobject.embedSWF(swf, "flash", "640", "480", "10.0.0", >"expressInstall.swf", params);
>
>       }; 
>
>        var swfRef = { 
>            a: "images/content/portfolio/Legal/01.swf", 
>            b: "images/content/portfolio/Legal/02.swf", 
>            c: "images/content/portfolio/Legal/03.swf", 
>            e: "images/content/portfolio/legal/04.swf", 
>            f: "images/content/portfolio/legal/05.swf", 
>            g: "images/content/portfolio/legal/06.swf", 
>            h: "images/content/portfolio/legal/07.jpg", 
>            i: "images/content/portfolio/legal/08.jpg" 
>        }; 
>
>       var imgRef = {
>           d: "images/content/portfolio/legal/09.jpg" 
>       };
>
>       var vidRef = { 
>            j: "images/content/portfolio/legal/10.mp4" 
>        }; 
>
>        $(function(){ 
>           $.each(swfRef, function(i, val){ 
>                $("#" + i).click(function(){ 
>                    putSWF(val); 
>                   $("#description").html( $($(this).attr('href')).html() );
>                   return false;
>                }); 
>            });
>
>           $.each(imgRef, function(i, val){ 
>                $("#" + i).click(function(){ 
>                    putSWF(val); 
>                   $("#description").html( $($(this).attr('href')).html() );
>                   return false;
>                }); 
>            });
>
>           $.each(vidRef, function(i, val){ 
>                $("#" + i).click(function(){ 
>                    putSWF(val); 
>                   $("#description").html( $($(this).attr('href')).html() );
>                   return false;
>                }); 
>            });                
>            $("#a").trigger('click'); 
>        }); 
>    </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

SwfObject doesn't embed videos. It will not work this way. You need to use a video player, or create a `<video>` element on the fly:

Here is a very basic way you could do this:

create a different method for launching the videos (than the swfs).  Something along these lines:

```
       $.each(vidRef, function(i, val){ 
           $("#" + i).click(function(){ 
               putVideo(val); //use a different function call 
              $("#description").html( $($(this).attr('href')).html() );
              return false;
           }); 
       });                
       $("#a").trigger('click');
```

---

```
function putVideo(vidUrl){
    $("#flash").html("<video><source src=\"" +vidUrl + "\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video");
    $("#flash video")[0].play();
}
```